# Using LINQ and Storing Results in a DataTable

Tags: c#

Firstly can I say, I am fairly new to programming and the C# language.

I am using LINQ to query a DataTable that I have made for specific results. I know this snippet works but for some reasons when I am running it through VS's debugger it is allocating the following to my variable:

```
var resultOne = from Rows in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where Rows.Field<string>("Column1") == SLSRResult
                //&& row.Field("B") == 2
                select Rows.Field<string>("Column2");
MessageBox.Show(string.Format ("Value is: {0}", resultOne));
```

Apologies if this question is vague or if the question itself is not in the correct format, this is the first time I am using this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultOne` is *not* a single string but an `IEnumerable<string>`, so possibly multiple. You either have to select a specific one(f.e. the `First()`), or use another method to get a single, for example `String.Join`:

```
string allResults = String.Join(",",  resultOne);
```

You could also enumerate all in a  `foreach`:

```
foreach(string str in resultOne)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format ("Value is: {0}", str));
```

If you know that there is only one or you are interested only in the first, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` (or `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` if multiple were incorrect):

```
string firstOfAll = resultOne.FirstOrDefault(); // null if there was none
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!